# Exportar relatório para PDF

Tags: delphi, relatório, pdf

Uso o `pReport` da extinta *VTK Tools* como gerador de relatórios no `Delphi XE7`. Ele não possui exportação nativa para `PDF`.
Hoje, exporto para `PDF` chamando uma impressora virtual com parâmetros.
Mas não quero mais ter que instalar em cada cliente uma impressora virtual.

*Como posso exportar nativamente um relatório para `PDF`?*

Pensei até em estudar como criar uma impressora virtual para `PDF` para então criar algum algoritmo parecido... mas não encontrei nada.

Comment: da uma olhada se possui nessa paleta de componentes algo como `Filter`

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Não possui... é uma palheta antiga, que não tenho como migrar para outra mais moderna. Ela possui exportação (`Filter`) para `Excel` e `HTML`.

Comment: Como se trata de uma ferramenta de Relatório, não acredito que seja possível adicionar de outra. Como ela é antiga e 'extinta', recomendo você fazer um esforço maior e construir seus relatório em um modelo mais moderno! É chato demais mexer com isso, mas no caso é necessário! FastReport, QuickReport, ambos nativos e eficientes, entre outros!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Já montei um conversor do `pReport` para `FastReport`, mas sem condições... Há muitas variáveis e muitos layouts cusmotizados nos clientes. Fazer essa conversão nessa altura do campeonato é muito *inviável*. Mas o que quero é conseguir gerar o `PostScript` do relatório e convertê-lo para `PDF`. Sei que é possível, só não sei ainda como...

Comment: A [Gnostice](https://www.gnostice.com/) tem algumas ferramentas bem interessantes não sei se tem suporte ao seu gerador mas vale uma olhada. Outro ponto, considere pegar alguma suite open source e tentar adaptar ou criar um filter PDF para o seu gerador, eu te indico o [FortesReport](https://github.com/fortesinformatica/fortesreport-ce), caso você tenha os fontes é claro.

Comment: Patrick, assim como sugeri a ele usar o FastReport e o QuickReport, também conheço a Gnostice e usamos junto ao QuickReport, responde bem no quesito gerar PDF. Quanto a criar o Filter também pensei nisto, mas o nível é Altíssimo.

Comment: Bom, para esse seu caso, a melhor opção é a migração de fato.
Você pode contornar temporariamente usando aplicativos semelhantes aqueles que simulam impressoras, como por exemplo o doPDF. Ao mandar a impressão para ela, basta salvar o documento.

Comment: Agradeço a todos, porém como já consigo gerar o `PDF` por meio de uma _impressora virtual_, vou tentar desenvolver um `Filter PDF`. Qualquer novidade, informo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todos os  comentários foram úteis, porém a melhor forma que encontrei para exportar os meus relatórios para `PFD` foi por meio da biblioteca `Synopse` (`SynPDF`).
É muito poderoso e fácil de se utilizar.
No meu caso é necessário percorrer os elementos do relatório gerado e montar o `PDF` na mão, porém se o gerador de relatório exportar um `MetaFile` (`QuickReport` faz, por exemplo), o trabalho fica bem mais fácil.

Mais informações nos links abaixo:
[Documentação](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=PDF+Engine)
[Ex. QuickReport](http://www.andrecelestino.com/delphi-exportando-relatorios-em-quickreport-para-pdf-com-o-synopse/)